# How to make text to 2. row

Tags: css, text

On photo you can see my problem,
[image]

Problem is because my first text is to long and don't show some letters on end,
I try with padding, margin ... not work i really don't know what to add there for this look like in 2. row

main

```
.qa-main {padding-left:20px; float:left; margin-bottom:2em; width:626px; clear:left; overflow:hidden;

.qa-q-view-extra {margin-bottom:18px; font-style:normal;}
.qa-q-view-extra-content {font-weight:bold; background:#FFF; color:#0ba200; font-size:15px; text-decoration:underline;}
```

Thanks.

Comment: You need to show your code mate.

Comment: Post your code please.

Comment: Hello, i add code, please check :)

Comment: Try deleting `overflow:hidden` or use `word-wrap`. Could you add the `HTML-code` too? Or perhaps a JSFiddle?

Comment: @CTravel word-wrap: break-word; work, Thanks Sir a lot :)

Comment: @user2047800 No problem! added it as answer ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add `word-wrap: break-word;` to the div.

```
.qa-main {
   ...
   word-wrap: break-word;
}
```